# How to load resource key in ascx files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I want to set one of my Link Button caption from Resource files, so i have the following code :

```
  <table >
  <tr >
        <td>  
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnRow" resourcekey="lbtnRow" CssClass="lablelinkbtn" runat="server" Text="Row" ></asp:LinkButton>
        </td> 
        <td>  
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnProcess" resourcekey="lbtnProcess" CssClass="lablelinkbtn" runat="server" Text="Process" ></asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
  </tr>
  </Table>
```

but if i call them from the code behind, it works well. but the string from resource file is not working

```
  string result = Localization.GetString("lbtnRow", LocalResourceFile);
```

Why they don't load in my ascx files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least i found the the problem. my file name was "EditProcess.ascx" and my resource file was "EditProcess.fa-IR.resx". in this case resourcekey property could not find the resource file it needed ".asx" extension in file name. so when i change the file to "EditProcess.ascx.fa-IR.resx" everything works well.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you have to call. did you call it like this?

```
Text="<%$Resources:LocalResourceFile,lbtnRow%>" 

//The Example
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnProcess" resourcekey="lbtnProcess" CssClass="lablelinkbtn" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:LocalResourceFile,lbtnRow%>" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

and please make sure your resource file is inside the "App_GlobalResources" folder

Comment: i want to use resources from App_LocalResources not global ones.

Comment: ok, without placing the file into global folder, the current solution is working?

Comment: and if it is local resource, try this example <asp:Label Text="<%$Resources: WebResources, Key%>" runat="server" />